# jquery token-input and active_admin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I want to use `jquery-token-input` with has_many relationship inside `active_admin`.

What is the best way to do it, and how can i implement it generically so that i can re-use the code for further has_many relationships.

I will be looking forward for your suggestion and guide lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, this doesn't use `jquery-token-input`, but it works!

I used [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/).

Download the CSS, JS and png files and put into the appropriate assets directory.

#### In `/app/admin/modelname.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Modlename do

#Customize create and edit form
form do |f|
    f.inputs do
       f.input :name
       f.input :othermodel, :input_html => { :class => "chosen-input" }
    end
  f.buttons
  end   
end
```

#### In `active_admin.js`

```
//= require chosen.jquery.min

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".chosen-input").chosen();
});
```

#### In `active_admin.css.scss`

```
/*
   *= require chosen
*/
```

Comment: I had accomplished the same thing with `jquery-token-input` with the same technique you described.

Answer (score 0):

There's a RailsCast on this that I was able to adapt in order to do this.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields

The only additional things to think about are making sure that the javascript and css are included in ActiveAdmin.

For the form in ActiveAdmin, here's what I used (in the file app/admin/story.rb)

```
ActiveAdmin.register Story do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Story details" do
        f.input :title
    end
    f.inputs "Issue Categories" do
        f.text_field :issue_tokens, data: {load: f.object.issues}
    end

    f.actions
  end
end
```

In this case, my models are Story and Issues, connected by a has and belongs to many relationship.

The only gotcha is that the token input seems to be getting overridden by active admin, trying to figure that one out.

**Update**
Add the following to app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.sass

```
@import "token-input";
@import "token-input-facebook";
```

This gets some of the needed styling going, but some work is still needed, I think due to clashes with active admin styling.